# What happened to Behrooz on "24"

Tags: 24

Whatever happened to Behrooz Araz, the unwitting son of the terrorist couple in Season 4 of the TV Series "24"? Last I remember, the bad guys had kidnapped him and then we never heard from his character again.

Answer (score 3):

His ultimate fate is unknown, however bonus footage on the DVD set for the season shows him being [rescued by CTU agents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_characters_in_24#Behrooz_Araz).

Thing is, if this bonus footage wasn't part of an extended cut or any sort of official cut of the series, it can't really be considered canonical.